# How to flag 3rd-party support questions?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Often, we see questions like "A 3rd-party site has my funds, help me recover". It could be that the web app screwed up, or maybe the user, or both.

It seems straightforward that these questions should be closed. Assuming that's correct, what flag should we use for them?

My first instinct is to close with Off-Topic, but I can't find an Off-Topic category that makes sense to me. Should we add a new category for 3rd-party application support?

Examples:

- [How to get Bittrex Support to share Personal Keys to ETH wallet? Does Bittrex Support offer assistance in tokens that are less than $5000?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25016/blunder-i-sent-eth-from-coinbase-to-etc-address-in-bittrex)
- [ERC 20 TOKEN NOT RECEIVED IN CCEX WALLET](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25072/erc-20-token-not-received-in-ccex-wallet)
- [Ethereum transaction stuck, out of gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/ethereum-transaction-stuck-out-of-gas) (actually, a poloniex deposit that they haven't recognized)

Comment: For off-topic, there is `Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)`.  The site doesn't allow us to add more custom reasons...

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't moderators allowed to edit these questions like so? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186031/how-do-moderators-update-custom-off-topic-reasons-for-their-site

Comment: You're correct custom reasons can be added but the site basically only allows us 2 of them :(  In the past we changed the 2 reasons we had a few times.  I noticed we could try asking for another extra reason.

Comment: CMs: Can we get an additional (fourth) custom reason per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons?rq=1#comment905797_279487 ?

Comment: Where do we draw the line for third party support? Exchanges and online wallets are clearly only answerable by their customer support (or other customers). But some question about Azure blockchain/Infura are likely the same.

Comment: I suppose it basically comes down to whether users can reasonably have access to the data required to debug the issue. There's going to be some judgement applied there about: 1) how open the system is and 2) how dominant of a product it is, such that many will know how to use it. So a closed 3rd-party system that has a monopoly may stay open, if it's clearly a user error.