# Are support question about EtherDelta on topic?

Tags: discussion

Most exchanges question fall into the third party support: [How to flag 3rd-party support questions?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/526/how-to-flag-3rd-party-support-questions)

But EtherDelta is a third party, but like other decentralized exchanges the contract's source is public. Some of technical questions can be answered (and even can be interesting).

Perhaps we should consider a line similar to: [Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/should-we-discourage-questions-about-exchanges-trading-buying)

> On topic:
>
> Asking how things work, e.g. how does exchange X choose which orders
>   to fulfill? Why doesn't this trading code work?
>
> Off topic:
>
> Any thing suggesting or asking for a view on valuation of something,
>   e.g. what do you think will happen to the price of Y?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the question.  Agree that asking how an aspect of some open source code works can be on topic.  A lot of questions are about why funds did not get sent or received, and so the community probably has correctly judged such questions to be off-topic.